# Generate a world map with folium and value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I have a problem. I want to create a world map with the help of [`folium`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html). I am using `value_counts`, because I want to show like a heatmap which countries occur most.

But unfortunately I do not know, how I could get the 'heads' `folium.Choropleth(...,columns=['Country','Total'],...).add_to(m)`. How could I generate a map with `value_counts`?

The point, is that `value_counts` does not give any heading. Is there any option to get the heading `columns=['Country', 'Total'],`

Dataframe

```
   id country
0   1      DE
1   2      DE
2   3      CN
3   4      BG
4   3      CN
5   4      BG
6   5      BG
```

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5], 'country': ['DE', 'DE', 'CN', 'BG', 'CN', 'BG', 'BG']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# print(df)
count_country = df['country'].value_counts()

[OUT]
BG    3
DE    2
CN    2
```

```py
import folium
#Creating a base map
m = folium.Map()

folium.Choropleth(
    data=count__orders_countries,
    columns=['Country', 'Total'],
    fill_color='PuRd',
    nan_fill_color='white'
).add_to(m)
```

Comment: To paint by country in folium, you need a geojson file with polygonal descriptions of the folium base map and country areas, and user data. And I need the short names of the names and countries defined in geojson and the short names of the countries in the user data. From your question, I think you need a geojson file. See [Using Choropleth class](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial it helpful. https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-simple-folium-map-covid-19-worldwide-total-case-a0a1429c6e7c

Apparently, there are two key points that you are missing:

1- Setting up the world country data. This is done through a URL that you pass to the folium.Choropleth geo_Data parameter.

> From the tutorial:
>
> ```
> #Setting up the world countries data URL
> url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-
> visualization/folium/master/examples/data'
> country_shapes = f'{url}/world-countries.json'
> ```

2- In your dataframe you need to have the names of the countries to match the data from the URL so you need to replace the names in your dataframe to these names.

For example in the tutorial they had to change the following names like this (the name of the dataframe with countries and data was called df_covid):

> From the tutorial:
>
> ```
> #Replacing the country name
> df_covid.replace('USA', "United States of America", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('Tanzania', "United Republic of Tanzania", inplace = 
> True)
> df_covid.replace('Democratic Republic of Congo', "Democratic Republic of > the Congo", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('Congo', "Republic of the Congo", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('Lao', "Laos", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('Syrian Arab Republic', "Syria", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('Serbia', "Republic of Serbia", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('Czechia', "Czech Republic", inplace = True)
> df_covid.replace('UAE', "United Arab Emirates", inplace = True)
> ```

3- Finally, create your map. PAss the URL to geo_data, the dataframe to data, and the column name that has the country and the counts to the columns.

> From the tutorial:
>
> ```
> folium.Choropleth(
>     geo_data=country_shapes,
>     name='choropleth COVID-19',
>     data=df_covid,
>     columns=['Country', 'Total Case'],
>     key_on='feature.properties.name',
>     fill_color='PuRd',
>     nan_fill_color='white'
> ).add_to(m)
> ```

Edit:
To get a data frame from the counts you could do something like this:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame()
df_input['Country'] = count_country.index
df_input['Counts'] = np.array(count_country)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do not know, how I could get my ISO code of the countries and the counts in the folium. `data=df` but `columns=[]`. What are the names of my columns? `value_Counts()` does not give me any headings.

Comment: @Test Check this out: https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/BB_Introducing_Z_Business/D_Country%2C_State%2C_and_Province_Codes/A_Country_Names_and_Their_ISO_Codes

Comment: @Test check the edit to create a data frame from the counts